# Comparing multiple perf reports

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I am using [Perf tool](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) for profiling.
I need to compare multiple reports generated from perf record command.
I couldn't find any option in perf to do so, is there a way for it or manual interpretation is the only way?

Comment: I could use that but I meant is there any perf-feature/tool available for it ?

Comment: (above is the answer of: Can you use a bash script. That question is deleted: it had an ugly typo)

Comment: I am doing that, but I am looking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **perf diff** for this purpose:
perf diff [oldfile] [newfile]

Link to man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/perf-diff